# Track exact location android/NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js

I'm creating a real time tracking app with NodeJS and Android as a client side but I am unable to get the exact location.

I can pull lat/long with the IP address, but that gets horribly inaccurate. Is there a way I can implement the maps api just to get the location coordinates and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact location you have to use the GPS on the phone. You will never get any exact data using the IP address.

Read this: [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) in Android docs.

Or if you're writing a hybrid app see: [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/).